# SwiftUI ScrollView margins of each item have increased and cannot be reduced

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview

[image]

When I use this method, the margins in my project have increased. I don't know how to handle it.

```swift
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  icbo2
//
//  Created by 张潇 on 2023/9/30.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            VStack(spacing: 0){
                Divider()
                
                HStack{
                    Text("当页人民币汇总")
                        .padding(.leading, 10.0)
                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                    
                    ZStack{
                        Text("收: +55，")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 206/255, green: 64/255, blue: 54/255, alpha: 1)))
                            .font(.system(size:14))
                            .padding(.trailing,20)
                        Text("345.45")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 206/255, green: 64/255, blue: 54/255, alpha: 1)))
                            .font(.system(size:14))
                            .padding(.leading,65)
                        
                    }
                    
                    Text("支: -0.00")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        .padding(.leading, 30.0)
                        .font(.system(size:14))
                    Spacer()
                    
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 7.0)
                
                ScrollView(){
                    singer(date:"2023年10月",date_number_one: "21", date_number:"10",week:"周二",week_one: "周六",shouru_lixi:"+0.13",shouru: "+14，",xiaoshu: "379.60",total:"16，",yue:"13.07",wan: "051.08",pad:5.0,pa:5.0)
                    Divider()
                        .padding(.leading, 50.0)
                    
                    singer(date:"2023年09月",date_number_one: "21", date_number:"11",week:"周一",week_one: "周四",shouru_lixi:"+0.13",shouru: "+14，",xiaoshu: "379.60",total:"16，",yue:"13.07",wan: "051.08",pad:5.0,pa:13.0)
                    Divider()
                        .padding(.leading, 50.0)
                    
                    singer(date:"2023年08月",date_number_one: "21", date_number:"11",week:"周一",week_one: "周四",shouru_lixi:"+0.13",shouru: "+14，",xiaoshu: "379.60",total:"16，",yue:"13.07",wan: "051.08",pad:5.0,pa:13.0)
                    Divider()
                        .padding(.leading, 50.0)
                    
                    singer(date:"2023年07月",date_number_one: "21", date_number:"11",week:"周一",week_one: "周四",shouru_lixi:"+0.13",shouru: "+14，",xiaoshu: "379.60",total:"16，",yue:"13.07",wan: "051.08",pad:5.0,pa:13.0)
                    Divider()
                        .padding(.leading, 50.0)
                    
                    singer(date:"2023年06月",date_number_one: "21", date_number:"11",week:"周一",week_one: "周四",shouru_lixi:"+0.13",shouru: "+14，",xiaoshu: "379.60",total:"16，",yue:"13.07",wan: "051.08",pad:5.0,pa:13.0)
                    Divider()
                        .padding(.leading, 50.0)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

            // 自定义导航栏标题内容
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("查询明细").fontWeight(.regular)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 96/255, green: 116/255, blue: 131/255, alpha: 1))).padding(.bottom, 2).font(.system(size: 20))
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: Button(action: {},
                label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 96/255, green: 116/255, blue: 131/255, alpha: 1)))
                }
            ),
            trailing: Button(action: {}, label:{Text("我的账户")
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 96/255, green: 116/255, blue: 131/255, alpha: 1)))}))

        }
    }
}

struct singer: View{
    var date: String = ""
    var date_number_one: String=""
    var date_number: String = ""
    var week: String = ""
    var week_one: String = ""
    var shouru_lixi: String = ""
    var shouru: String = ""
    var xiaoshu: String = ""
    var total: String = ""
    var yue: String = ""
    var wan: String = ""
    var pad: Double=0
    var pa: Double=0
    var body: some View{
        
        HStack{
            Text(self.date)
                .fontWeight(.regular)
                .font(.system(size:19))
                .padding(.top,self.pad)
                .padding(.bottom,3.0)
                .padding(.top,self.pa)
                .padding(.leading,8.0)
                
            Spacer()
        }.background(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 245/255, green: 245/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1)))
        HStack{
            Text(self.date_number_one)
                .font(.system(size: 23))
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 96/255, green: 116/255, blue: 131/255, alpha: 1)))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding(.horizontal, 15.0)
            
            Text("利息")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .font(.system(size:15))
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 51/255, green: 51/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 1)))
            Spacer()

                Text(self.shouru_lixi)
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 206/255, green: 64/255, blue: 54/255, alpha: 1)))
                .padding(.trailing,15)
        }
        HStack{
            Text(self.week_one)
                .font(.system(size: 12))
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 96/255, green: 116/255, blue: 131/255, alpha: 1)))
                .padding(.horizontal, 15.0)
            
            Text("批量业务").font(.system(size: 13))
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 96/255, green: 116/255, blue: 131/255, alpha: 1)))
            Spacer()
            
            ZStack{
                Text("余额:"+self.yue)
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 96/255, green: 116/255, blue: 131/255, alpha: 1)))
                
            }.padding(.trailing,15)
        }
        Divider()
        HStack{
            Text(self.date_number)
                .font(.system(size: 23))
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 96/255, green: 116/255, blue: 131/255, alpha: 1)))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding(.horizontal, 15.0)
                
            Text("他行汇入")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .font(.system(size:15))
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 51/255, green: 51/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 1)))
            Spacer()
                
            ZStack{
                Text(self.shouru)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 206/255, green: 64/255, blue: 54/255, alpha: 1)))
                Text(self.xiaoshu).padding(.leading,70)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 206/255, green: 64/255, blue: 54/255, alpha: 1)))
            }
            .padding(.trailing,15)
        }
        HStack{
            Text(self.week)
                .font(.system(size: 12))
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 96/255, green: 116/255, blue: 131/255, alpha: 1)))
                .padding(.horizontal, 15.0)
                
            Text("xxx科技有限公司").font(.system(size: 13))
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 96/255, green: 116/255, blue: 131/255, alpha: 1)))
            Spacer()
                
            ZStack{
                Text("余额:"+self.total)
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 96/255, green: 116/255, blue: 131/255, alpha: 1)))
                    
                Text(self.wan)
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 96/255, green: 116/255, blue: 131/255, alpha: 1)))
                    .padding(.leading,80)
                    
            }.padding(.trailing,15)
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 3.0)
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I don't know where to set or add any attributes

Answer (score 0):

Your `singer` view has lots of top-level `HStacks`, but there is no container around them, so the layout and spacing is left up to the parent view which holds the `singer` instances. This might explain why the spacing is different when you use a `ScrollView` as the parent, compared to whatever you were using when it wasn't a `ScrollView`.

Try adding a `VStack` with explicit spacing as the top-level container to the `body` of `singer`. You could start with `spacing: 0` for a really compact layout:

```swift
// struct singer
var body: some View{
    VStack(spacing: 0) { // <- ADDED
        HStack{
            Text(self.date)
                // modifiers as before
            Spacer()
        }.background(Color(UIColor(displayP3Red: 245/255, green: 245/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1)))
        HStack{
            // content as before
        }
        HStack{
            // content as before
        }
        Divider()
        HStack{
            // content as before
        }
        HStack{
            // content as before
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 3.0)
    }
}
```

[image: Compact]

For less padding at the bottom, try reducing or removing the bottom padding on the last `HStack` and also on the content inside the last `HStack`.